# Microsoft SQL is it possible to concatenate the result of two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, concatenation

I have a table with the following information: customer, line, text. The values of line are 1-5, corresponding to the days of the week, Mon-Fri.  We might see data like:

```
|Customer | Line | Text | 
|123      | 1    | 018  |
|123      | 3    | 030  |
|234      | 2    | 129  |
```

Customer 123 is seen on Monday and Wednesday and customer 234 is seen on Tuesday.

I want to generate one line for each customer that looks like:

```
123   Mon     Wed
234       Tue
```

I can use

```
select Customer, DaysOfWeek = 
case text
    when '' then '    '
    else 'Tue '         
end  
from routing where customer = %s and line = '2'
```

Which will generate "Tue" when %s = '234'.

When I stack five of these with each one having a line number 1 through 5 separated by UNION, I get two separate rows for Mon and Wed for customer 123.  I can't get it to put the results of all the select statements on one line.  I've tried CONCAT, &, +....  I'm stuck.

Comment: What SQL are you using?

Comment: Does "Microsoft SQL" as you use it mean Microsoft **SQL Server** ? Or do you refer to Microsoft **Access** SQL ?? Please add the `sql-server` or `ms-access` tag to clarify - thanks!

Comment: Just a quick thought before I head out to my son's baseball game...you could write five queries each representing a day. The queries would use a where clause. You would then join all five queries together to make your final result. I will write these queries as an answer as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Ghost I'm trying to configure data output on an app.  I have no idea what they are using for SQL on the app.  We have Microsoft SQL Server on our servers for checking the source databases.  We were told to use SybaseCentral UltraLite to look at the database we extract from downloaded "containers" (.ipa files and their data).  Queries that run in Ultralite _usually_ return good results in the app, but not always.

Comment: @TychaBrahe does your query work in the "app" or have you just been testing in Ultralite? I'm thinking maybe Serg's SQL would work if you changed the alias to the end and used the 'As' keyword.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right,

```
select Customer, 
  Day1 = max(case line when '1' then 'Mon ' end),  
  Day2 = max(case line when '2' then 'Tue ' end),  
  --..       
from routing 
where customer = %s 
    and Len(text) > 0 -- skip empty text rows
group by Customer
```

This query will return single row and columns for every day of week needed.

Comment: I like this.  It worked in MS SQL Server, and it worked in Ultralite when I changed Len() to Length().  I just can't get it to work in our app.  Experimentation continues.

Comment: @Serg I never thought about writing a SQL statement like the select clause in this query. It appears it's the alias, but at the front. I've done this with variable, but it's never dawned on me to try this in a normal query. I think I'm really going to like it. :) I haven't tested this so please correct me if I'm wrong in thinking it's used that way.

Comment: @Michael this is really alias but this style is supportet by a  few DBMSes only including MS SQL.

Comment: maybe that is why the query doesn't work in the OP's app. It's a nice feature and I use SQL Server so I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:
First with cases and exists function, for example:
select

```
case when exists (SELECT 1 FROM routing r1 WHERE r1.customer=r2.customer AND r1.Line=1) then 'Mon' else '   ' end ||
case when exists (SELECT 1 FROM routing r1 WHERE r1.customer=r2.customer AND r1.Line=2) then 'Tue' else '   ' end
[... next days...]
from routing r2 group by r2.customer
```

Second approach it is more complicated and uses PIVOT selects, but it is not supported by all db engines.

Comment: This also works in both MSSQL and UltraLite, but doesn't work in our app.  And before you ask, I have no idea what the developers are using for SQL in the app.  I just do configuration.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try my SQL query, I'm confident it will work for you even though it's not the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your app:

If it does not work as a CTE (Common Table Expression) in your app then I will translate to nested queries which should work for sure.

```
    WITH CUSTOMERS AS 
  (SELECT DISTINCT Customer
    FROM routing),
  DAY1 AS 
(SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 1
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> ''),
  DAY2 AS 
(SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 2
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> ''),
  DAY3 AS 
(SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 3
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> ''),
  DAY4 AS 
(SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 4
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> ''),
  DAY5 AS 
(SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 5
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '')
SELECT CUSTOMERS.Customer,
  CASE WHEN DAY1.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Mon' END AS 'Mon',
  CASE WHEN DAY2.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Tue' END AS 'Tue',
  CASE WHEN DAY3.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Wed' END AS 'Wed',
  CASE WHEN DAY4.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Thu' END AS 'Thu',
  CASE WHEN DAY5.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Fri' END AS 'Fri'
  FROM CUSTOMERS
  LEFT JOIN DAY1
  ON CUSTOMERS.Customer = DAY1.Customer
  LEFT JOIN DAY2
  ON CUSTOMERS.Customer = DAY2.Customer
  LEFT JOIN DAY3
  ON CUSTOMERS.Customer = DAY3.Customer
  LEFT JOIN DAY4
  ON CUSTOMERS.Customer = DAY4.Customer
  LEFT JOIN DAY5
  ON CUSTOMERS.Customer = DAY5.Customer
```

Ok, I went ahead and created the nested query version. I'm very confident this will work in your app.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT C.Customer,
  CASE WHEN DAY1.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Mon' END AS 'Mon',
  CASE WHEN DAY2.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Tue' END AS 'Tue',
  CASE WHEN DAY3.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Wed' END AS 'Wed',
  CASE WHEN DAY4.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Thu' END AS 'Thu',
  CASE WHEN DAY5.Line IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Fri' END AS 'Fri'
    FROM routing C
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 1
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '') DAY1
  ON C.Customer = DAY1.Customer
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 2
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '') DAY2
  ON C.Customer = DAY2.Customer
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 3
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '') DAY3
  ON C.Customer = DAY3.Customer
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 4
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '') DAY4
  ON C.Customer = DAY4.Customer
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer,
        Line
  FROM routing
  WHERE Line = 5
  AND isnull(Text, '') <> '') DAY5
  ON C.Customer = DAY5.Customer
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would make it incompatible with your app is the isnull() function. You can try to change that if it fails.